# How get I the ref of props.children property to use 'measure' method?

Tags: reactjs, native

I'm looking for a way to measure a children property of a component. I tried React.createReference, passed reference (ref) as property to component B, read properties from this.props.children of component B ( anyone know a documentation for props.children?) - all without success.

Phantasy code:

```
class A extends Component {
   render(){
      return(){
         <B>
           <Text>Component to references</Text>
         </B>
      }
   }
}

class B extends Component {
   getChildBounds(){
      this.props.children.measure((dx,dy)=>{
            console.log(dx,dy);
         }
      )
   }
   render(){
      this.getChildBounds();
      return(){
         <View>
           {this.props.children}
         </View>  
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: try logging this.refs and see if you are getting it there or not

Comment: @Shubham Agarwal Bhewanewala this.refs is an empty object.